# Simple C# Error when compiling and running the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to learn C# by watching tutorials and when I try to rename my class it gives me this

So this first error is basically when I make a new console solution and then declare a class and give it a name and then try to write out to the console it gives me two errors.

> ![1ST:Error   1   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration   C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   10  23  ConsoleApplication1
>
> 2ND : Error   2   The type name 'Writeline' does not exist in the type
>   'System.Console'  C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   10  13     ConsoleApplication1

I clicked an save all and saved it to a folder on my desktop where I plan to put all my C# files but I get those errors and when I start out a new document clean it and write the console commands and build it doesnt give me any errors.

Is it that I need a constructor or that I need to save my files in a specific order or what?.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOtcl.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have a call to `System.Console.WriteLine` outside of the body of a method. The compiler thinks you are trying to reference a type, which does not exist, and it is also telling you that `(` is not legal at that particular point in the code file.

You likely have a class definition that might look something like this

```
class Program
{
     System.Console.WriteLine("hello world");
}
```

What you need is a class definition that looks more like

```
class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          System.Console.WriteLine("hello world");
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey I used to be able to write the Console.WriteLine() but why do I have to reference System.Console now?

Comment: I simply showed the fully qualified way of invoking the WriteLine method on the System.Console class. But as long as you have a `using System;` directive inside your class file (usually at the *very* top), you can omit the `System.` and use `Console.WriteLine("blah");` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Anthony Pegram’s answer is correct. Adding the directive `using System;` at the top of any relative c# files, allows the compiler to omit the need to have the **System.** portion of the method namespace in front of `System.Console.WriteLine()`.

However, if the console solution is named **TestSolution** and the console application project has the namespace **TestSolution.Console**; the **System.** declaration in front of `System.Console.WriteLine()` calls will still be needed.

This is due to ambiguity in the compiler as to the **Console** portion ending in the namespace. A console project named **TestSolution.TestConsole**, will not run into the namespace collision, unless the name of the class being written is **Console**.

Watch for potential naming collisions for namespaces, when building and naming libraries for .NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues.

Firstly, you are trying to call Console.WriteLine() in an invalid part of the file. You need to declare a `Method` or `Constructor` and place this call inside that.

Constructor example:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Method example:

```
public class Person
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Your other issues is that you have the capitalization of 'WriteLine' incorrect.

The code should read:

`Console.WriteLine("Test");`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've blown away the `Main()` method. Also, you shouldn't (can't, I guess) just have a method call floating in a class - it has to be within a method or constructor.

Try replacing the  contents within `namespace ConsoleApplication1` with the below get you started:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person alan = new Person();
        alan.PersonName = "Alan";

        Console.WriteLine("Hi " + alan.PersonName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

**PS.** You probably should have Person in a separate file (e.g. Person.cs) but for getting started this should do....not the ideal end state, though.